# OWL API build failed with ANT

Tags: java, build, owl, owl-api

I download OWL API 3.2.4 from http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/download.html

and build it with ANT.

There are some errors show on the terminal:

```
$ ant

Buildfile: /home/yichu/owlapi-3.2.4/build.xml

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/yichu/owlapi-3.2.4/build

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/yichu/owlapi-3.2.4/build/classes
    [javac] /home/yichu/owlapi-3.2.4/build.xml:57: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

binjar:
     [exec] Result: 1
      [jar] Building MANIFEST-only jar: /home/yichu/owlapi-3.2.4/build/owlapi-bin.jar

srcjar:

BUILD FAILED
/home/yichu/owlapi-3.2.4/build.xml:139: /home/yichu/api/src/main/java does not exist.
```

What do the errors mean?

Thank you!